# CheckinAll:The file encoding -3 is not a valid encoding

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

While resolving conflict, I will get `The file encoding -3 is not a valid encoding.`

I am resolving conflict on folder.

Code :

```
workspace.MergeContent(conflict, false);
```

Error:

```
The file encoding -3 is not a valid encoding.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.FileType.GetEncodingFromIntOrString(Int32 codePage, String encoding)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PreMerge(Conflict conflict, ThreeWayMerge threeWayMerge)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.InternalMergeContent(Conflict conflict)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.MergeContent(Conflict conflict, Boolean useExternalMergeTool)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you but I have a similar issue and I found out that the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Service Pack 1 made a fix regarding encoding problems.

> Fixed issues:
>
> Very aggressive automatic detection of file encoding can result in
>   unsuitable encoding mismatches during merges

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182621#mtDisclaimer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182621)

Comment: I have Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 4 Object Model Installer

Comment: Here is a question I wrote on the MSDN forum that maybe could help you :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d37f750-a2fb-4bb3-9e0b-8abfeba067dc/opening-the-resolve-conflicts-window-programaticly?forum=tfsversioncontrol